# how to make nested loops in python for passing a string?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-3.6, nested-loops

I was trying to do the nested loop for string in python and the output is one string is repeating. The program shown below,

```
recipients = ['123@gmail.com', '456@gmail.com', '789@gmail.com']
t = Template('$email')

message = ['employee1', 'employee2', 'employee3']
n = Template('$name')


def get_email_text():
    for i in draftnotification.recipients:
        recipient = draftnotification.t.substitute(email=i)
        print(recipient)
        for j in draftnotification.message:
            names = draftnotification.n.substitute(name=j)
            print('hi '+names)
        text = 'Fee Summary Report'
        print(text)

    return text
```

the output is,

```
123@gmail.com
hi employee1
hi employee2
hi employee3
Fee Summary Report
456@gmail.com
hi employee1
hi employee2
hi employee3
Fee Summary Report
789@gmail.com
hi employee1
hi employee2
hi employee3
Fee Summary Report
```

hi employee is repeating need to get the output like is showing below

```
123@gmail.com
hi employee1
Fee Summary Report
456@gmail.com
hi employee2
Fee Summary Report
789@gmail.com
hi employee3
Fee Summary Report
```

kindly looking for someones help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` function for this

```py
recipients = ['123@gmail.com', '456@gmail.com', '789@gmail.com']

message = ['employee1', 'employee2', 'employee3']

for i, j in enumerate(recipients, 0):
    print(f'{j}')
    print(message[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going over every element in `message` every time you process a new `recipient`.

Instead, use `zip()` to bind each recipient to its corresponding message:

```
def get_email_text():
    for i, j in zip(draftnotification.recipients, draftnotification.message):
        recipient = draftnotification.t.substitute(email=i)
        # Rest of the for loop is the same, omitted for brevity.
        ...
```